# Reproducing MongoDB's map/emit functionality in javascript/node.js (without MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mapreduce

I like the functionality that MongoDB provides for doing map/reduce tasks, specifically the emit() in the mapper function.  How can I reproduce the map behavior shown below in javascript/node.js without MongoDB?

### Example ([from MongoDB Map-Reduce Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)):

```
[{ cust_id: "A123", amount: 500 }, { cust_id: "A123", amount: 250 }, { cust_id: "B212", amount: 200 }]
```

#### Mapped to -

```
[{ "A123": [500, 200] }, { "B212": 200 }]
```

A library that makes it as simple as Mongo's one line emit() would be nice but native functions would do the job as well.

Comment: Have you checked out [Underscore.JS](http://underscorejs.org/)?

Comment: I have, but I was unable to figure out how to use _.map to produce the same results.

Comment: With [].map, [].reduce and [].forEach as built-in methods these days (and a whole bunch more as the first answer links to), you don't really need libraries. It's convenient for compatibility to use Underscore, because it provides them when they are missing, but extra dependencies are only a good thing if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just neeed to have the `emit` syntax, it's possible. Scan out the function body and pass in a new emit function.

```
function mapReduce(docs, m, r) {
  var groups = {}
  function emit(key, value) {
    if (!groups[key]) { groups[key] = [] }
    groups[key].push(value)
  }
  var fn = m.toString()
  var body = fn.substring(fn.indexOf('{') + 1, fn.lastIndexOf('}'))
  var map = new Function('emit', body)
  docs.forEach(function (doc) {
    map.call(doc, emit)
  })
  var outs = []
  Object.keys(groups).forEach(function (key) {
    outs.push({ _id: key, value: r(key, groups[key]) })
  })
  return outs
}
```

Edit, forgot example:

```
var docs = // from above

Array.sum = function (values) {
  return values.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b })
}

mapReduce(docs, 
  function () {
    emit(this.cust_id, this.amount)
  },
  function (k, values) {
    return Array.sum(values)
  }
)

// [ { _id: 'A123', value: 750 }, { _id: 'B212', value: 200 } ]
```

Comment: I'll add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwzqm98g/) for this. Thank you. This was the functionality I was looking for.

Comment: Nice example, although it contains some weird things: why convert the map function to a string and mess around with the function body just to inject emit? Why Array.sum? If you want to add a new method to each array you have to use Array.prototype.sum.

Answer (score 2):

Array.reduce does what you need. 
here is documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

I also suggest you to use undescore.js (as in first comment) which has reduce & reduceRight. 
http://underscorejs.org/#reduce

Answer (score 0):

I agree that there are lots of great lib ways to do this, and it's simple to do with Array methods. [Here is a fiddle with my suggestion](http://jsfiddle.net/6u5jegyq/). It's pretty simple, and just uses the forEach Array method. I've done it in a single loop, but there are many other ways.

I haven't done the reduce at the end, as you didn't ask for that, but I hope this helps.

```
function emit (key, value, data) {
    var res = {}; out = [];
    data.forEach(function (item) {
        var k = item[key];
        var v = item[value];
        if (k !== undefined && v !== undefined) {
            if (res[k] !== undefined) {
                out[res[k]][k].push(v);
            } else {
                var obj = {};
                res[k] = out.length;
                obj[k] = [v];
                out.push(obj);
            } 
        }
    });
    return out;
}

var data = [{name: 'Steve', amount: 50},{name: 'Steve', amount: 400}, {name: 'Jim', amount: 400}];

emit('name', 'amount', data)) // returns [{"Steve":[50,400]},{"Jim":[400]}]

emit('amount', 'name', data)) // returns [{"50":["Steve"]},{"400":["Steve","Jim"]}]
```

I've used an object to store the array index for each unique entry. There are lots of versions of this. Probably many better than mine, but thought I'd give you a vanilla JS version.