# Pouchdb join / link documents

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, mapreduce, pouchdb

I have pouchdb/couchbase data with equipment that has user assigned to them.
Equipment with _id and in the equipment doc there is a checkedOutBy with the user._id as the value. Within the employee object there is user.name. When I get the equipment objects how do I also get the user.name and display with the equipment.

I have searched and read about map/reduce that uses emit and do not grasp the idea. My code that i wrote from what i learned is:
by the way I am also using Angularjs.

```
    field = "eq::"
this.getAllEquip = function(field){
            function map(doc) {
                if (doc.checkedOutBy !== undefined) {
                    emit(doc.checkedOutBy, {empName : doc.name});
                }
            }
            var result = database.query(map, {include_docs: true,
                            attachments: true,
                            startkey: field,
                            endkey: field + '\uffff'})
                .catch(function (err) {
                //error stuff here
            });
            return result
        };
```

I don't see where the two docs would get together. What am i missing? My result is empty.

The equipment json looks like:

{checkedOutBy: "us::10015", description: "3P Microsoft Surface w/stylus & power cord", equipId: "SUR1501", purchaseDate: "", rCost: 1000, id:"eq::10001"}

Emlpoyee json:

{"firstname":"Joe","gender":"male","lastname":"Blow","status":"active","title":"office","type":"userInfo","_id":"us::10015","_rev":"2-95e9f34784094104ad24bbf2894ae786"}

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please share sample data and show what you are trying to do, so that we can understand the query better.

Comment: I have added json sample, thanks

Comment: So in your getAllEquip function, you have both "equipment" and "Employee" objects and the function should return the equipment object with the "firstname" key added to it based on the "_id" value which is the same as "checkedOutBy" in equipment? Also confirm if you will have multiple Equipment and Employee objects and if its an array of objects?

Comment: First, yes multiple equipment and employee objects. only one employee per equip. multiple equip for one employee. As i have it now the getAllEquip is to get only equipment for a list/table. In That list i want to show the name of the employee instead of the employee id that is in the equipment object.

Comment: Would the solution below work? If not please let me know what changes are there based on the example below so that I can look at it.

Comment: It looks like that could work. I will give it a try. Do you know how to use the map function with emit? That looks more simple but i don't understand how it works.

Comment: that should be fine. The length of the array should not be an issue here. Please check if you are getting the expected result.  Also, I havent used the map/emit solution. Saw this thread. You can check it out as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535027/reproducing-mongodbs-map-emit-functionality-in-javascript-node-js-without-mong

Comment: I have used you suggestion and tailored it to my code. I get the name of the employee and then i get to your code of 'result.push(tempObj);'   Where does the "result" part come from? oh i see it now, i will work it more.

Comment: That did it thanks

Comment: Could you mark as the accepted answer, if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my Pouchdb solution, thank you Vijay for leading me to this solution.
First I get all my equipment.   Then I use Vijay's idea to loop through the array and add the name to the object and build new array. I found there is a need to go into the .doc. part of the object as in  obj.doc.checkedOutBy and tempObj.doc.name to get the job done.

```
$pouchDB.getAllDocs('eq::').then(function(udata){
                var result = [];
                //loop through equipment array 
                udata.rows.forEach(function(obj) {
                    var tempObj = obj;
                    var checkedout_id=obj.doc.checkedOutBy;

                    if (checkedout_id != undefined) {
                        $pouchDB.get(checkedout_id).then(function(emp){
                            return emp.firstname + " " + emp.lastname
                        }).then(function(name){
                            tempObj.doc.name = name;
                        });
                    }
                    result.push(tempObj);
                })
```

in my service I have:

```
this.get = function(documentId) {
            return database.get(documentId);
        };
```

and:

```
this.getAllDocs = function(field){
        return database.allDocs({
          include_docs: true,
          attachments: true,
          startkey: field,
          endkey: field + '\uffff'});
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, if I understood the question correctly:

```
        //Sample Array of Objects with Equipment 
 var arr1=[{checkedout:"abc1",desc:"item1",id:1},
     {checkedout:"abc2",desc:"item2",id:2},
    {checkedout:"abc3",desc:"item3",id:3},
    {checkedout:"abc1",desc:"item1",id:4},
    {checkedout:"abc4",desc:"item3",id:5},
    {checkedout:"abc6",desc:"item3",id:6}];

//Sample array of objects with Employee - the "id" in arr2 matches with "checkout" in arr1  
            var arr2=[{name:"john",id:"abc1"},
    {name:"jack",id:"abc2"},
    {name:"alice",id:"abc3"},
    {name:"james",id:"abc4"}];

    var result = [];  //final result array

//loop through equipment array arr1
    arr1.forEach(function(obj) {

    var tempObj = obj;

    var checkedout_id=obj.checkedout;

    //do array.find which will return the first element in the array which satisfies the given function. This is absed on the assumption that that the id is unique for employee and there wont bwe multiple employees with same id (which is the "checkedout" field in equipment. If the employee is not found, it will return undefined.
    var foundname = arr2.find(function(obj) {

    if (obj.id  == checkedout_id)

     return obj.name

    })

  //Create the object to be inserted into the final array by adding a new key called "name", based on the result of above find function  
    if (foundname != undefined) {

    tempObj.name=foundname.name

    }
    else {

    tempObj.name = "Not found";

    }


    result.push(tempObj);


    })
```